# I bought a second hand pack of pieces and it looks like it may be a specific set

Tags: set-identification

Hoping for help to identify a set of lego pieces. It definitely has a car wheel base, and the base boards are green.close

[image: Pile of LEGO elements]

Answer (score 6):

A lot, but definitely not all, is likely from [Race 3000](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=3839).

[image]

Comment: That's great thanks so much... Definitely the race 3000 pieces, just putti together.... Still have a heap of pieces and cars... Not sure if this is a set or to....